# What is the difference between \s and \t?

Tags: regex

They both seem to work but I have been told you should use both when you're forming a RegExp?

Comment: i think this is a general regex question.  maybe take out javascript,html tags and change the title.

Comment: \s denotes whitespace and where as \t denotes tab

Comment: Just a pedantic adjustment to what most answers are saying here: `[\s\t]` is redundant.  The `\t` is already part of `\s` so you don't have to include the `\t`.  In the case of `\s\t`, the `\t` is not redundant.  It is looking for a whitespace, followed by a tab. So be careful if you're dealing with a character class or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\s` matches a single whitespace character, which includes spaces, tabs, form feeds, line feeds and other unicode spaces.

`\t` Matches a single tab.

If you are using `\s`, you don't need to include `\t`.

More information on regex patterns here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 18):

`\s` matches any whitespace character, including tabs. `\t` only matches a tab character.

`\t` being a subset of `\s`, you should not have to use both at the same time.

Comment: I wouldn't call `\t` a subset as a much as an "element of" `\s`.

Comment: A one-element subset?

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Answer (score 3):

`\t` is a *literal* tab whereas `\s` is a predefined [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `\s` matches *any* whitespace character while `\t` matches *only* tabs (which are also matched by `\s`).

This is similar to asking what the difference between `\d` and `0` is. `0` is a literal `0` whereas `\d` is any digit.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` contains all whitespace characters. For example, in Java, `\s` is `[\t\n\x0b\r\f]`. `\t` is just a single tab, so you don't need to use both.